# Xamarin forms grid not rendering row/columns

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, grid

I have a grid in which I add moreTileView. but its just rendering in the first row and column (overlapping each other). What I want is for every new "tile" to be rendered in a new row and/or a column. Maybe this isnt the best way of doing this. If you guys have a batter idea how to achive what I'm trying to do, please let me know.

MoreTilePage.xaml

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout  x:Name="MoreTileViewHolder" />
    <ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

MoreTilePage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MoreTilePage : ContentPage
{
    public MoreTilePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var items = PixelApp.Platform.AppContext.Instance.moreViewModel?.Items;

        Grid myGrid = new Grid();

        myGrid.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        myGrid.Padding = new Thickness(10);

        myGrid.RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection
        {
            new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(220) },
            new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(220) },
            new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(220) },
            new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(220) },
            new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(220) }
        };

        myGrid.ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection
        {
            new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Star },
            new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Star }
        };


        int iColumn = 0;
        int iRow = 0;
        int iItem = 1;


        foreach (MoreModel model in items)
        {
            if (iItem > 2)
            {
                iItem = 1;
                iRow++;
            }

            model.row = iRow;
            model.column = iColumn;

            var tile = new MoreTileView(model);
            myGrid.Children.Add(tile);

            iItem++;

            if (iColumn == 0)
                iColumn = 1;
            else
                iColumn = 0;
        }

        MoreTileViewHolder.Children.Add(myGrid);
    }
}
```

MoreTileView.xaml

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <Frame Grid.Column="{Binding column}" Grid.Row="{Binding row}" Margin="0" HasShadow="True" BackgroundColor="LightGray" IsClippedToBounds="True" CornerRadius="10" Padding="0">
        <Grid>
            <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="{Binding image}" Aspect="AspectFill" />
            <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="https://www.fisher-price.com/resources/animations/Imaginext/meetcharacters/images/kids_bkg-grey-grad.png" Aspect="Fill" />

            <BoxView HeightRequest="3" BackgroundColor="HotPink" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Start" WidthRequest="70" Margin="10,10,10,60" />
            <Label Text="{Binding headline}" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="End" Margin="10,10,10,10" />
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
</ContentView.Content>
```

MoreModel.cs

```
public class MoreModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int appId { get; set; }
    public int sort { get; set; }
    public string headline { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }

    public int column { get; set; }
    public int row { get; set; }
}
```

[This is what the output is on excecution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5Kzu.png)

[However this is what I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUrz0.png)

Comment: I set my grid background color to red and I still see NOTHING. Xamarin sucks

Answer (score 0):

Puhhh... there are many flaws.

**1.** Why put the grid in the stacklayout as its the only child? Just put the grid directly into the scrollview. `MoreTileViewHolder.Children.Add(myGrid);` is therefore useless. Just replace `<StackLayout  x:Name="MoreTileViewHolder" />` with `.

**2.** You add all your "tile" objects to Column 0 and Row 0 of the grid `myGrid.Children.Add(tile)`.

You have to specify the row and grid when adding, otherwise they end up at the same spot.
`myGrid.Children.Add(tile, iColumn, iRow)` seems like this is what you are intending.

I know you are trying to do this with Bindings on the Grid.Column and Grid.Row-Properties. But I guess this is not updating the view. My guess is these Properties are changed at a wrong point in time, so adding it to the Grid won't have an effect.
Despite that, you have to show us your "MoreModel" class. It could also be, that you are not using BindableProperties correctly, so the `Grid.Column="{Binding column}"` on the `Frame` just never really happens.

**3.** Don't reinvent the wheel. The latest xamarin version includes the "FlexLayout" which I believe does what you intent to create here. [Xamarin FlexLayout](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/FlexLayoutDemos/)

Comment: I dont understand "2. You add all your "tile" objects to Column 0 and Row 0 of the grid myGrid.Children.Add(tile).", how come? I'm looping through all the item and setting:

    model.row = iRow;
    model.column = iColumn;

and the bindings should also be correct since I'm getting the headline in the label correctly.

Comment: But the headline text refers to the label itself. The binding of the Grid.Row is refering to a parent object (the myGrid) and might be set too early/too late, so it doesnt apply the values. Still, why do you bind these values? You have them right there when you add the views to the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand "2. You add all your "tile" objects to Column 0 and Row 0 of the grid myGrid.Children.Add(tile).", how come? I'm looping through all the item and setting:

```
model.row = iRow;
model.column = iColumn;
```

and the bindings should also be correct since I'm getting the headline in the label correctly.